# Conversion from shared_ptr to weak_ptr polymorphism

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I am having trouble getting around this one.
Let's say I have this vector

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>> cars;
```

Car is an abstract class.
I want to be able to return weak pointers of different types so I do the following.

```
template<typename T>
    std::weak_ptr<T> GetCar()
    {
        for (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>>::iterator it = cars.begin(); it != cars.end(); ++it)
        {
            T* derived = dynamic_cast<T*>((*it).get());
            if (derived != nullptr)
            {
                std::weak_ptr<T> carPointer = *it;
                return carPointer;
            }
        }
        return std::weak_ptr<T>();
    }
```

I get the following error though when I try to use the function with a class that inherits from Car.
`Error  C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr<Car>' to 'std::weak_ptr<Saab>'`

There might not be a valid car when asked for it. I tried using boost::optional but it does not handle polymorphism . I might go with raw pointers if I can't get this to work.

Comment: The type pointed to by `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` must be the same. I'd do this in three steps: return a `weak_ptr<Car>` then convert it into a `shared_ptr<Car>`, then to a `T*`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @MarkRansom Mmm. This is for a user function of a library, so I'd rather not give the developper that might use it more work. Should have said so, my bad. Would you recommand working only with raw pointers so I can return one?  Or returning derived even,

Comment: You can certainly have a single function that performs all three steps, but the purpose of converting a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` is to keep the object alive while you're working with it; putting the `shared_ptr` into a temporary defeats that purpose.

Comment: Does `std::weak_ptr<T> carPointer = std::shared_ptr<T>(*it);` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't construct directly your `weak_ptr<Saab>` from the `shared_ptr<Car>` because the template parameter `Car` must implicitly be convertible to `Saab` in order to work.

But you can first convert your `shared_ptr<Car>` to `shared_ptr<Saab>` at first then construct your `weak_ptr` afterward. In my example below, I used the `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to do it.

Here is what I came up with :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Car
{
    virtual void name() = 0;
};

struct Saab : Car
{
    virtual void name() { std::cout << "Saab" << std::endl; }   
};

struct Renault : Car
{
    virtual void name() { std::cout << "Renault" << std::endl; }   
};

template<typename T>
std::weak_ptr<T> GetCar(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>> cars)
{
    for (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>>::iterator it = cars.begin(); it != cars.end(); ++it)
    {
        auto derived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(*it);
        if (derived != nullptr)
        {
            std::weak_ptr<T> carPointer(derived);
            return carPointer;
        }
    }
    return std::weak_ptr<T>();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>> cars;
    cars.push_back(std::make_shared<Saab>());
    cars.push_back(std::make_shared<Renault>());

    auto wp = GetCar<Saab>(cars);

    auto sp = wp.lock();
    if (sp)
    {
        sp->name();
    }

    auto wp2 = GetCar<Renault>(cars);

    auto sp2 = wp2.lock();
    if (sp2)
    {
        sp2->name();
    }

}
```

It prints out :

> Saab
>
> Renault

Coliru link : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dbb85b556b83597